# google spreadsheet script - permissions to protect sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following spreadsheet:

-Template (protected)

-Current working sheet

-older sheet (protected)

-even older sheet (protected)

This spreadsheet is shared with a few users, and they have write permission in the "current working sheet". Once it is considered completed, I created a button in the "current working sheet" to which I assigned a script. When ran as owner, the script:

1. renames the "current working sheet" to "something older"
2. protects the "something older" sheet
3. duplicates the "template" sheet as a new "current working sheet"

It all works fine wen ran by owner, however when the button that triggers the script is pressed by one of the users whom I shared the document with, then step (2) fails, meaning the sheet can't be protected. I suspect this is a permissions issue but I am a complete newbie in google scripting, so I am asking for some help here. Is there any way to make sure that no matter who presses the button, the assigned script is ran as owner?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a button which the user at the keyboard clicks invoke a script which runs as the owner. See the [doc about authorization here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#permissions_and_types_of_scripts). That said, what you **can** do is have the button set a value or update a record which a script on a **time based trigger** checks. A flow like this would work well:

1. User updates the working sheet
2. User clicks the `I am done!` button
3. Script adds a row to a hidden sheet called `Things for scripts to do` which indicates that as of now, the working sheet should be archived
4. Every hour, a script checks `Things for scripts to do` and updates sheets and permissions as described above